# ntdll.pdb not found on x64 build VS2019

Tags: c++, arm, visual-studio-2019, apple-m1

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2019 on a virtual machine running windows 11 on a new Macbook pro.  I have the simplest program possible, the hello world program in c++, and when I try and run it in x64 configuration, it throws an exception from ntdll.dll saying ntdll.pdb cannot be found.  I turned on the Microsoft symbol server and it still does not work.  Does anyone know of any workaround for this or is just a dead thing at the moment because VS is not optimized for ARM architecture?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello There" << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFBDE88234 (ntdll.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

Everything works as expected on x86.

Comment: pdb files are debugger information. For something like as tightly integrated with the operating system as ntdll, the pdb file is next to useless. You're effectively debugging the operating system. Even if you've tripped over a bug in the OS there's smurf all you can do about it. Code you have shouldn't be tossing a null pointer exception anywhere, though, so there's some sort of misconfiguration that'll be really tricky to figure out without sitting at your computer and poking around.

Comment: Totally missed the note about the ARM CPU at the end. Probably the problem, but like debugging the OS, I'm not sure what you can do about it. Does anything 64 bit run on in the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes it does 64bit emulation for most stuff.  I got Tales of Arise to run on it pretty well so its probably a Visual Studio problem.  I tried doing Get-ChildItem in powershell to search for the ntdll.pdb file but it kept getting access denied errors even when I did runas Admin.

Comment: Way out of my area of competence at this point, but I can say that if somehow it turns out that the null pointer is the result of a missing pdb file, somebody smurfed up hard. It's much more likely that something in the program's execution blew up, triggered a halt in ntdll, and the pdb request is simply the debugger trying to give you as much information as possible. Why did the program blow up? It shouldn't have.

Comment: Yeah it says Source not Found and throws that null pointer so I'm thinking someone forgot to add something to the servers or something like that.  Because it only blows up on x64 builds and even a brand new empty c++ project does it.  Thanks for trying to help though lol.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue too. My work needs both environments (unix + windows) and I'd like to switch over to an M1 if possible. Any luck so far?

Comment: No luck yet and probably not anytime soon, unfortunately. Seems like this issue is at the bottom of the list for MS, see the not supported section of this says doesn't work in a Virtual Machine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/system-requirements